# How can I install ADA IDE and compiler on Mac (OS X)?

Tags: ada, gnat

I downloaded GNAT ADA GPL 2014 and am now trying to install on my Mac.

The directions below are the ones I am following, but where can I find the file called `doinstall`?

1. Navigate to the directory that contains a file called: `doinstall`
2. Enter: `sudo mkdir /usr/local/gnat`
3. Enter: `sudo ./doinstall`
4. Update your path as needed for your shell

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should have downloaded `gnat-gpl-2014-x86_64-darwin-bin.tar.gz`.

Go to some temporary directory (I use `~/tmp`):

```
cd ~/tmp
```

Unpack the download, which creates a directory `gnat-gpl-2014-x86_64-darwin-bin` containing the binary distribution to be installed:

```
tar zxvf ~/Downloads/gnat-gpl-2014-x86_64-darwin-bin.tar.gz
```

Enter that directory, which contains (amongst others) `doinstall`:

```
cd gnat-gpl-2014-x86_64-darwin-bin
```

Execute `doinstall` to enter the installation dialog:

```
sudo ./doinstall
```

Remove the unpacked download:

```
cd ..
rm -rf gnat-gpl-2014-x86_64-darwin-bin
```

*Now* you can update `PATH` as needed for your shell.

Answer (score 1):

What [Simon Wright said](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28100240/how-to-install-ada-ide-and-compiler-on-mac-osx/28107348#28107348) is correct, but if you're running on [Mac OS X v10.10](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OS_X_Yosemite) (Yosemite), there's an extra problem: for some obscure reason, Adacore GNAT is broken on Yosemite. You have to make it think it's compiling for [Mac OS X v10.9](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OS_X_Mavericks) (Mavericks):

```
export MACOSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET=10.9 # Yosemite workaround
```

That can go in a few different places, but I put it near the top of the */usr/local/gnat/bin/gps* script, so it doesn't interfere with the xcodebuild environment.

Also, I found GTKAda to be nearly impossible to install from source; if you download the XNAdaLib-GPL package from *[The GNU Ada compiler](http://sourceforge.net/projects/gnuada/)* you can install that and get everything you need without having to wade through Adacore's mess. (You may want to use the Adacore version of [Glade](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glade_Interface_Designer) for GUI design though; for some reason the Sourceforge package's version is localized in French and I'm not sure if it can be switched to English.)

Finally, since this is a bit duct-tape-and-baling-wire, I would recommend not shipping any production mission-critical code with this environment; either roll back to Mavericks or wait for GNAT 2015.